# Apple App Store + Phonegap Automatic Updates

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have found many similar questions but nothing identical to what I am asking. I am building an app using Phonegap.

It seems that Apple allow apps that request external JS (people using Google Maps and so on), So basically by using a `<script>` tag in the header and referencing the external js file. My problem is that I want to do something similar but via code, so using jquery getScript.

The functionality all works, but my only worry is that apple say you cannot download code to your app. Surely having a script tag in the header of the app referencing external javascript is exactly that, downloading javascript to the app.

Its basically, exactly the same in my opinion, no matter how you grab the javascript, it's still technically 'downloading' code.

Anybody know the true answer to this, if not, how do I find out? Even if the app was approved, there is nothing to stop me building 20 apps with this code just to find in future that I was lucky and they take them all down.

Comment: Second paragraph appears to be clipped "...So basically by using a" .. using a what?

Comment: Submit the damn thing and find out, Apple can and do change the rules without warning, it's in the TOS. There's no one here who can predict the future. As far as downloading javascript code goes, it seems to be ok, for the moment.

Comment: basically using a script tag in the header I think I was going to say!! I would just submit, but we are planning anywhere from 10 - 100 apps using this same core code. If we hit 100, I would not want to have to go back through each and every single app. There is also the potential for the account to be banned if they think we have done something deliberately.

Comment: If your commercial strategy relies on these apps, then you must package up all the code, and deploy it with the app. But you have to understand that the App Store is a law unto itself, essentially, get  in, launch and make $$$'s invest in converting apps that are successful to native / ObjC. It's unfortunately a risky game at the edge of the TOS, and that's where PhoneGap/Cordova lives

Comment: in a nutshell, don't even entertain the idea of trying to bend the rules.

Comment: I find Phonegap as a platform absolutely fine and for apps such as mine, no reason to build native at all (games and so on, I would expect at this stage to be still much better native - but that will eventually change). My issue is that the guidelines for submission almost seem to be based on the past where this kind of situation did not exist, which doesn't help at the moment where this would seriously provide a great method to keep apps up to date and bug free quickly and efficiently

Comment: No, you misunderstood, I meant make it native to keep your app investment safe within the AppStore, there's nothing wrong with them other than that Apple can pull the carpet from under them. And I agree, it'd be great if you could do your updates like that, but Apple provide a method to do this, and they don't appear to want people going around their velvet rope. The only issues you have are all TOS related, (and more importantly on its "changes without prior notice" clause.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's submission policies, not programming.

Answer (score 3):

there are mixed opinions about it. some developers have been given a hard time for approval of the app when using phone gap. i personally prefer not to use it. here is a link to a discussion that has the opinion of many developers.
http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Anyone-uses-PhoneGap-on-iOS-72283.S.106288557

https://devforums.apple.com/message/513221

as i said there are mixed opinions about it. using phonegap does not prevent your app from being approved, but it is clearly mentioned in the doc's that apps that download codes will be rejected. according to apple there is no issue with having javascript codes inside the app but you cannot execute a set of code to download the script into the app from outside. it has to be inside your app. i hope this makes sense to you. but all in all if you are building an app that downloads codes it will be rejected, if you are building an app that has the script inside it and downloads the dialogue ( like Facebook) related to it, no problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. My experience with phonegap has been mixed, but overall, a very effective way to get apps quickly off the ground. This issue is more of a technicality in the rules of Apple. You mention if it downloads a dialog such as Facebook that is no problem, surely that is downloading further code 'into' the app that is not 'bundled' with it? It's almost as if there is an 'invisible' list of safe code people assume will be fine such as google maps and facebook and so on but bespoke js cannot be done in the same way.

Comment: I have seen it approved in special cases. It is done but not officially. All in all those who get to bend the rules of apple are lucky. Happy coding and good luck my friend.

Answer (score 0):

apple doesn't allow you to load code later on.
Exceptions are part of every rule but the general opionen about this is clear and I wouldn't rely on that

Answer (score 0):

The spirit of this 'guideline' is to ensure the functionality of the app doesn't change in any significant way after Apple's approval. [Apple is even locking down ability to change screenshot after approval](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=1092013a). This more for security, still the goal is the same. To consistently present the functionality of your app.

Inferring from the title of your question , are you are using `<script>` or `getScript` to ensure latest version to the device, as opposed to packaging the app and updating the app?